# Background music & Video

Tags: java, html

I need for my website a background music that stops when i play a video (not youtube embed video)  and starts again/continues when the video ends.

How can i do that? Can someone give me an example maybe where the audio tag has the  ID audio and video the ID video?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<video onplay='pauseAudio()' onpause='playAudio()'></video>
<audio id='audio'></audio>
```

JS

```
audio = document.getElementById('audio');
video = document.getElementById('video');
function pauseAudio(){
   audio.pause();
}
function playAudio(){
   audio.play();
}
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. My code is:

JS.

<script type="text/javascript">

audio = document.getElementById('audio');
video = document.getElementById('video');
function pauseAudio(){
   audio.pause();
}
function playAudio(){
   audio.play();
}

</script>


HTML.

<video id="video" onPlay="pauseAudio()" onPause="playAudio()" controls width="680" height="480">
        <source src="Mein Film_7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> 
        
        
  <audio id="audio" loop=true>
        <source src="Two Steps From Hell - Heart of Courage (Extended Version).mp3">
         </audio>

Comment: Hmm I've tested it on FF and Chrome and  it worked. Make sure, that the javascript code comes AFTER the HTML. And maybe add the `autoplay` attribute to the `audio` tag so that it plays automatically when the site loads

Comment: I made an adjustion. I had autoplay in, yes, i think i got it out to test something.
Either way, i replaced all the "audio" with just an simple "a" and it worked. I think somewhere, somehow, it didn't recognized about whats going on...

I thank you very much. The code works perfectly now.